# passing data within business logic layer

Tags: java, design-patterns, business-logic

I am working with JDK 7.

I have all my business logic classes in `com.srh.bll.businesslogic` package.

**I am concerned about how to return data from one business logic class to another business logic class.**

For example I have 2 business logic classes `ReferenceYearBusinessLogic` and `AnniversaryBusinessLogic`. 
Now `methodA` of `ReferenceYearBusinessLogic` needs to call `methodA` of `AnniversaryBusinessLogic` and expects to get 3 things back: referenceDate, anniversaryNumber and vacationRate. 
And `methodC` of `ReferenceYearBusinessLogic` needs to call `methodB` of `AnniversaryBusinessLogic` and expects to get 2 things back: payScale and payRate. 
And so on...

So I think I need to define classes to pass data in this case; one class would have 3 properties: referenceDate, anniversaryNumber and vacationRate while another class would have 2 properties: payScale and payRate.

What would be these classes called in design pattern world? I thought of them as DTOs but DTOs are used to transfer data between layers while in my case they will be used only within one layer and will not be needed outside of that layer. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

writing code is all about imagination . somethign that is easier to read , very simple ,  performant and easily testable. if I were in this situation probabley might create a domain class to bundle these parametrrs {referenceDate, anniversaryNumber and vacationRate} and another class for payScale and payRate.  these classess maynot be end with  DTO naming convention.